# Minecraft Server makes PC lose internet

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, windows-10

So, I have a Minecraft Java Edition server running on 1.18.1, it has a few of the vanilla tweaks data packs on it and it does not have any mods. I have been running the server for a few months and my PC would sometimes disconnects from the internet while the server is running. I would have to reboot the PC in order to get the ethernet connection to work again.

However, recently it has been disconnecting within 2 minutes of launching the server. My PC works fine until I start the Minecraft server. I have already contacted Microsoft support to try and resolve the issue. I have flushed all internet settings, replaced all network drivers, completely reset my PC, and reinstalled Windows 10.

Something important: The Minecraft server itself does not crash, the PC's internet does, and when it happens, my PC will say that it is connected to the router, but that there is no internet. I have to reboot the PC to get the ethernet to work again. My router is an Arris NVG468MQ running with Frontier.

Comment: Is the server running on your PC? Is the server still reachable when your PC loses connection?

Comment: Yes, I host the server on my PC, and when my PC loses internet, no one can access the server, and it kicks anyone who is on the server.

Comment: Sounds like it could be a router problem if your pc still is connected to the router. Do other devices, such as your phone, still have internet/ a WiFi connection?  You could try to unplug your router, wait like 1 min and plug it back in. Might solve your issue...

Comment: When my PC disconnects, other devices in the house still work, and I will try that thanks

Comment: I tried rebooting the wifi, and the issue persists

Comment: Could you try using Linux/WSL to run the server? it’s possible either Windows or your router could be messing with it

Comment: I'm having this same exact issue on a 1.18 pack as well as a 1.12.2 pack. I've never had this issue until this year. The only thing that I've done that you haven't listed is disabled Winsows' ability to disable an adapter if it uses too much power.

Comment: I'm also having the issue it's incredibly random when it happens too. Has anyone figured it out yet? I just got a new pc it never happened on my prior pc

Comment: Are you using a port for your server different from the standard 25565 one?

Comment: Did you look at the related questions? While old, [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/21067/296788) answer has some sensible points like updating your network adapter or trying to run the server on a virtual machine.